# Visualización cortada en formulario de Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Realizo esta consulta porque no he podido encontrar en la web algo similar. 
El problema recae en que al depurar mi aplicación C#, cuando se maximiza cualquier formulario, se ve de manera Errónea. Básicamente se ve de manera correcta en en el recuadro superior izquierdo hasta cierto punto, y luego se ve mal. Este es un ejemplo de como se visualiza.

[image: Mala visualización]

Y este como se debería visualizar

[image: Como debe visualizarse]

Estoy desarrollando en C# Visual Studio 2015 en una máquina de 64bits, con framework de destino 4.5.

He probado modificar la plataforma de destino, tanto en x86, x64 como Any CPU por si esto podía estar influyendo y nada.

La máquina esta configurada con una resolución de pantalla de 1920x1080. Comento esto porque si modifico la resolución de pantalla cuando estoy depurando comienza a verse de manera correcta, pero al inicio de cualquier resolución se ve mal.
Así mismo, si en lugar de depurar, inicio la aplicación sin depuración también se ve de manera correcta.

El problema no se debe a la falta de asignación de las propiedades anchor o dock ya que formulario de la imagen contiene un SplitContainer, donde el panel de la izquierda contiene el label y la caja de texto ambos con Anchor en Top, Left, y el botón agregar con Anchor en Top, Right. Debajo de los mismos, un DataGridView con Anchor en Top, Bottom, Left, Right. En el panel derecho, el botón importar, tiene Anchor en Top, Right y el DataGridView tiene Anchor en Top, Bottom, Left, Right. El SplitContainer tiene a su vez el anchor en Top, Bottom, Left, Right.

El problema se da en que se redimensionan de manera correcta hasta el punto de corte que se ve en la primer imagen. Incluso, si tengo el formulario sin maximizar se ve mal hasta esas lineas, y cuando mueve el formulario al sector superior izquierdo se vuelve a ver bien. Cuando redimensiono mas allá de esas lineas verticales y horizontales se vuelve a ver mal. Es por esto que ´creí que pueden ser problemas con la resolución. De hecho, si Inicio el proyecto sin depurar se ve de manera correcta. Esto pasa con todos los formularios, tanto con el MDIContainer como con cada formulario dentro del mismo. Ninguno de mis otros proyectos reproducen este problema.

Comment: nada.. no pasa nada.. estas teniendo problemas de refresco en tu monitor.. puede ser drivers de placa de video, windows muy ocupado.. si se arregla al modificar la resolucion es solo eso.

Comment: Revisa la propiedad Dock de la grilla. fijate si esta en Fill, si no, colócala.

Comment: No se debe a un problema de drivers o recursos, ya que los mismo están actualizados, y los recursos de sistema por debajo del 25%.
Si bien dock = fill no es el comportamiento que deseo sobre la grilla, el hecho establecerlo no representa ningún cambio, el redimensionamiento se efectúa hasta cierto ciertos puntos, tanto horizontal como vertical, en donde se detiene. Me sorprende que éste mal funcionamiento se de únicamente al momento de iniciar la aplicación en modo de depuración, y no así iniciando sin depuración. Si compilo la aplicación y la ejecuto también funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso no ayuda mucho poner tamaños fijos a los controles, modifica la propiedad `dock` a `fill` para que el control abarque el 100% del espacio del control en el que esta contenido.  También te puedes apoyar utilizando `panels`, mira el ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si bien dock = fill no es el comportamiento que deseo sobre la grilla, el hecho establecerlo no representa ningún cambio, el redimensionamiento se efectúa hasta cierto ciertos puntos, tanto horizontal como vertical, en donde se detiene. Me sorprende que éste mal funcionamiento se de únicamente al momento de iniciar la aplicación en modo de depuración, y no así iniciando sin depuración. Si compilo la aplicación y la ejecuto también funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que mencionas que esto se pasa únicamente cuando ejecutas el programa en modo debug...

Podrías probar:

Limpiar la solución:
Compilar > Limpiar solución
Compilar > Compilar

Con esto recompilas todo lo necesario para ejecutar el binario resultante de tu proyecto.

Si esto no te da resultado, podés ejecutar paso a paso a partir del `InitializeComponent()` de tu form inicial en modo debug, y luego en modo release. Con esto deberías ver donde está la diferencia, si es que hay algo a nivel código.